# Why are the contents of this dialog behaving so weirdly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Here's an example of what I'm talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/167bqchz/

The border of the dialog doesn't extend down over the contents, and the contents are "squished" really thin. If you remove the contents completely, the border is fine and everything is as expected, but as soon as you put anything else in there, it starts behaving weirdly again.

Why is this behaviour happening, and how might I go about fixing it?

Edit to add: I am running Firefox Aurora (Developer Edition) on Arch Linux. Have not tested with any other browsers or OSes.

UPDATE: Tested on Chromium on Arch Linux, and I have this same bug too. Weird thing? In this case, it works fine in the fiddle, but not at all in my actual site, hmm...

Screenshot:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="pool-dialog">
    <div class="dual-list list-right col-md-3">
        <h2><i class="fa fa-times"></i>&nbsp;Not Selected</h2>
        <div class="well">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">Testaaaaaaaaaaa</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Testaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Testaaaaaaaaaaaa</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Testaaaaaaaaaaaaa</li> 
                <li class="list-group-item">Testaaaaaaaaaa</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.dual-list {
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.list-group {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.list-group-item {
    max-height: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.well {
    padding: 10px;
}

.ui-dialog {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: white;
}

.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    float: right;
}

.ui-dialog-titlebar {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? what is the expected result you want to achieve?

Comment: i saw the fiddle, and it's working just right.... maybe the close button?

Comment: @Lupin Not working here on Firefox Aurora on Linux. Behaviour is as I have described.

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano I do not speak of the close button, in the final version of what I'm making the close button won't exist so it doesn't matter how it looks right now.

Comment: @Lupin Sorry for useless comment, that was meant for the other guy. I have updated the post with a screenshot of what is happening.

Comment: well, my guess its a CSS compability issue but i have no wat to test this, sorry

Comment: to me seems a problem with jQuery not able to compute the needed width of the contained elements. can you set the min-width and min-height in the `.dual-list` and see if this solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the problem myself. It turns out that I should not have `.col-md-3` on the `div`. I copied this code from another part of my code where the `.col-md-3` was needed, and neglected to remove it. Removing it has fixed it.